# Select rows with some records having duplicated value in one column

Tags: sql, select, duplicates, row

I would like to retrieve all rows from a table where there are some records with a duplicated column, but i have to select only one row for those cases.

```
Example: 
 -------------------------------------------
| id   |   text          | stringIdentifier |
|-------------------------------------------
| 1    |  exampleTEXT1   | NULL             |  
| 2    |  exampleTEXT2   | NULL             | 
| 3    |  exampleTEXT3   | X13UIWF          |
| 4    |  exampleTEXT3   | X13UIWF          |
| 5    |  exampleTEXT3   | X13UIWF          |
| 6    |  exampleTEXT4   | A78BCTK          |
| 7    |  exampleTEXT4   | A78BCTK          |
| 8    |  NULL           | NULL             |
| 9    |  NULL           | NULL             |
 -------------------------------------------

Expected output: 
 -------------------------------------------
| id   |   text          | stringIdentifier |
|-------------------------------------------
| 1    |  exampleTEXT1   | NULL             |  
| 2    |  exampleTEXT2   | NULL             | 
| 3    |  exampleTEXT3   | X13UIWF          |
| 6    |  exampleTEXT4   | A78BCTK          |
| 8    |  NULL           | NULL             |
| 9    |  NULL           | NULL             |
 -------------------------------------------
```

Notes:

- I can select any row from the set of records with the same `stringIdentifier`
- Only column `id` is `PRIMARY KEY`
- It could be rows with `text = NULL` and `stringIdentifier = NULL`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `rank()` to choose only the first time ordered by `id` where any `text` appears.

```
select  id
       ,text
       ,stringidentifier
from   (
        select  *
                ,rank() over(partition by text order by id) as rnk
        from    t 
       ) t
where  rnk = 1 
or     text is null
```

| id | text | stringidentifier |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | exampleTEXT1 | null |
| 2 | exampleTEXT2 | null |
| 3 | exampleTEXT3 | X13UIWF |
| 6 | exampleTEXT4 | A78BCTK |
| 8 | null | null |
| 9 | null | null |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Zkyagrq5)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE id IN
    (
        SELECT MIN(id) FROM table
        GROUP BY text, stringIdentifier
    );
```

Here we are selecting rows where their ID is in the second statement (the one in parenthesis). This second statement is grouping rows by `text` and `stringIdentifier` and then from each grouping selecting the `MIN(id)` or minimum ID value. As there is only one minimum ID value per `text/stringIdentifier` pairing we end up with unique rows.

If you would like to keep ALL rows where `text` is NULL and `stringIdentifier` is NULL you can just add this to the end:

```
 OR (text IS NULL AND stringIdentifier IS NULL);
```

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to clarify one case. Your answer works perfectly, but it could exists a case where column "text" could be also null. I will edit the post. Thank you very much.

Comment: You've not specified how you would like to handle the null-case. Do you want to include all rows with nulls?